# Extract all files from Samsung Galaxy S8 Note (no root)

Tags: android, adb, smartphone

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8 Note from a customer who bought it from a "trustable" second-hand shop called asgoodasnew and the smartphone price was paid by rates by the original owner and it seems they didn't pay the remaining rates.

asgoodasnew sent a warning to the new owner [my customer] that if the rates aren't paid by end of 2020, the smartphone will be locked in 3 days and this screen pop up 10s after the loading screen disappears 
 [image: Locked phone photo]

- The phone is not rooted and has OEM firmware and recovery
- It seems Developers Option and USB Debugging are disabled, and I'm unsure if `adb` can help (if yes, how?)

asgoodasnew is willing to exchange the smartphone, but how can I get data from 2 apps, S-memo and Samsung Contacts, for my customer?

- Is there a command to copy all files beginning from `/` to my PC

Comment: Is there a Google account registered on the device? Usually contacts are automatically synced with the Google cloud. Samsung has also a cloud system, not sure if it also syncs contacts. You can check [Google contacts in the web](https://contacts.google.com) by logging is using the Google account used on the phone.

Comment: my customer did not sync it with google

Comment: If @Robert's comment isn't fruitful, any cellphone store with a [CelleBrite](https://www.cellebrite.com/) can likely get the data. While I'm not familiar with Samsung's OS, you should be able to boot Safe Mode, which prevents all third-party apps from running, via the bootloader menu _(google how to access the bootloader menu for that device, as it's often Vol Up+Power)_.

Comment: @JW0914 As far as I know CelleBrite often does not use official way instead they use vulnerabilities and that is what you pay for. And before going the hard way mentioning the easy ways is not a bad idea.

Comment: @Robert A CelleBrite machine is what's been used to transfer information to and from phones by cellphone stores for over two decades

Comment: I know what a CelleBrite is but it seems you are not aware how it actually works: it is an automated phone hacking machine. Of course it also uses the official interfaces like USB-MTP or adb, but it's real power lies in it's hacking capabilities.